# more than one home?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Is there a way I can have 2 homes in one town? I finished all my expansions but I really wish my house had more rooms because there's so many furniture sets I want to get but no room in just one house.

Answer (score 3):

As the Mayor you can only own one home, however you have 2 options that would let you show off all of your sweet, sweet furniture.

**Start a second, third or fourth character in your town...**

You can create up to 4 player controlled characters, including the mayor, in your village; each one of those characters can own a house. You would need to upgrade these houses, like you did for your Mayor's house, so this would be an expensive and lengthy endeavor.

*[This option would give you 18 extra rooms for 22,787,400 bells and take roughly 19 days.](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Your+House)*

**Invest in exhibition galleries at your local museum...**

While it isn't owning a second home, it is much cheaper to open the four exhibition galleries on the second floor of the museum. You can display any furniture, wallpapers, or flooring you'd like there. The downside is that you are limited to 4 rooms (exibits).

[*This option would give you 4 8x8 rooms for 40,000 bells.*](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Museum+Shop#Exhibition%20galleries)

Answer (score 1):

No. There can only be 1 house per player. However you create another character by choosing "New Save File" on the main menu in the game.

You can also put furniture and stuff like that in the second floor at the museum [once you've unlocked it](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/museum-shop/).